# Is there a list of Bloomberg DDE commands?

Tags: bloomberg, dde

I'm trying to interface with Bloomberg Pro using [DDEExecute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2swc2ces%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) but I'm having trouble finding a list of valid DDE commands.

In particular what I'm hoping to do right now is enter specific non-character keystrokes (e.g. "right arrow")

Comment: What are you trying to do via Bloomberg? If you're trying to get data out, are you aware that there's a pretty good API?

Comment: Yes!  This data wasn't accessible via the API at the time (although by now it may well be)

Comment: What data are you trying to get out?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with others that API is the way to go, but if for some reason you do not have the data, you can use a few different approaches including DDE or Sendkeys. I don't believe there is a list though, as bloomberg has said "Although the DDE and SendKeys functionality is documented here, we are unable to assist with specific uses of this functionality"

SendKeys method can be used in the following way:

```
' Activate a Bloomberg Professional Window (Window #1, in this case)
 AppActivate "1-BLOOMBERG"
 ' Send commands to the Bloomberg Professional service Window
 SendKeys "{ESC}" & "MSFT US {f8} DES~", True
```

Additional help on the "SendKeys" methods [Syntax of the keystrokes] can also be found in the MSDN Library - VBA Help Files, as well as in the Add-Ins Help file. This file can be opened from the Windows task bar by clicking the START menu and then Programs|Bloomberg.

The list including right arrow can be [found here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-sendkeys-method-excel).